# Data is not inserting into table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My table name is `Customer`. It has four columns

```
CustomerId
CustomerName
CustomerAddress
PhoneNo
```

This is my c# code. I am not getting any exceptions and data is not inserting into database.

```
string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VictoryDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

try
{
   myConnection.Open();
   string query = "insert into Customer(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,PhoneNo) values (@CustNm,'@CustAdd',@Ph)";
   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query,myConnection);
   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustNm",Print[0].CustomerName);
   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustAdd",Print[0].Address);
   myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ph",Print[0].Telephone);

   Console.WriteLine(Print[0].Telephone);

   myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: for clarification.. you are getting no rows inserted at all, or does it insert a blank row?

Comment: what does ExecuteNonQuery return?

Comment: Is CustomerId setup as an AutoIncrementing PK on the Customer table? Also, you do not need the single quote (') on the '@CustAdd' param;

Comment: As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the .mdf file and **most likely**, your INSERT works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong MDF file** in the end! If you want to stick with it - try putting a breakpoint on the `.Close()` call on your connection - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with e.g. SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

Comment: @NoCarrier it is not inserting any row.

Comment: @AlexMendez yes you are right.

Comment: The **real solution** would be to (1) install SQL Server Express, (2) install SQL Server Management Studio Express, (3) create your database **in SSMS Express**, and (4) connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances and all that crap!

Comment: Yes I don't understand the desire to use this AttachDbFilename and User Instance nonsense. Doesn't that create a new version of the MDF every time you build/compile/debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `VictoryDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VictoryDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: +100 - there must be a tutorial somewhere that describes this "User Instance" approach and in the fine print it says "PS don't use this."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: yes, most likely - haven't found it yet, though (in the vast MSDN sea of documentation.....)

Comment: But i have already created 8 tables database in the visualstudio name victorydatabase will it be portable to ` SQL Server Management Studio Express`

Comment: @Hira: **YES!** - you just fire up SSMS Express, put your `.mdf` file in the proper location (where the other `.mdf` files are located), and then you can **attach** that MDF file and you're done!

Comment: @marc_s thanks your answer help me a lot now everything is working fine thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

What you say simply doesn't happen. Either the query will insert a record, or you will get an exception.

There is an error in your query, though. There shouldn't be apostrophes around the `@CustAdd` parameter, that will make the database interpret that as a literal string, not a parameter:

```
string query = "insert into Customer(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,PhoneNo) values (@CustNm,@CustAdd,@Ph)";
```

I'm not certain how the database would react, but you would either get an exception telling you that you have a parameter that is never used in the query, or it would insert a record with the value `@CustAdd` as the address.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you're looking at the right database to verify that no
   data is being inserted?
2. Are you performing this insert within the
   context of a transaction that isn't being committed?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify the same paramets, (forgot to add "@" do it like:

```
string query = "insert into Customer(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,PhoneNo) values (@CustNm,'@CustAdd',@Ph)";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query,myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustNm",Print[0].CustomerName);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAdd",Print[0].Address);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ph",Print[0].Telephone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is CustomerId setup as an AutoIncrementing PK on the Customer table? Also, you do not need the single quote (') on the '@CustAdd' param;