# Northwind.sdf Not Updating In Simple Sample App

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm working through the "Demo: Binding Data with the SqlDataSource" of [this pluralsight video on ASP.NET Webforms.](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-03&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)

All communication with the database works just fine, except it won't change when updates are made.  The only thing I've done differently from the video is to use Northwind.sdf instead of Northwind.mdf.  The database exists in the project directory, which is under my Users directory on win7 -- so it shouldn't be a permissions problem.

What could be preventing it from updating?

In case anyone wants to try the sample app, I uploaded the whole project folder [here on mediafire.](http://www.mediafire.com/?aryzf4uzbz1at7p)

Comment: Are you using settings like `user instances` and/or `AttachDbFilename`? If so, stop doing that. See marc_s's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382756/data-is-not-inserting-into-table

Comment: I didn't touch either of those settings.  Keep in mind everything was built in Design mode using Webforms, and I followed the tutorial exactly.  In all 3 controls, the data source connection string is "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.sdf" and there is only the 1 sdf file in the projects data directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have two copies of the database.  You are updating copy A and then checking copy B.

Or, it could be one of the reasons described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/10/16/why-sql-updates-fail-three-reasons.aspx

Comment: Hi Steve, See my comment to the OP above -- there is only 1 file in the project's data directory.  None of the reasons listed in that article seem to apply to this case either, unfortunately