# Why do you need to attach an existing database file to an instance of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say we have a website that uses a mdf file. The website store a connection string in the  web.config file and the connection string contains the name of the SQL Server instance to be used and the physical path of the mdf file, which is all the information the website needs in order to use the database. From here I conclude an application does not need to register its mdf file with the SQL Server instance in order to work, so what is the point of attaching a mdf file to an instance? SO that we can use Management Studio on the mdf file?

**Edit:** The connection string stored in my website's web.config is:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data
Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlinePhotoGalleryDB.MDF;Integrated
Security=True;User Instance=True" />
```

I did not need to attach to an instance in order for my website to use the database, and I'm quite sure it is not a file based database.

Comment: The *website* does not "use the database", strictly-speaking. It requests that the database management system access the database on its behalf. If I understand what you are asking, that should suggest the answer: It is SQL Server that needs the mdf file "registered", not the "application"

Comment: 1) please post your connection string, 2) do you have access to the log file (.ldf), 3) can you connect as an admin the SQL Server instance

Comment: @AndrewBarber maybe the OP is confusing a SQL Server Express Edition with a Standard or higher Edition

Comment: @ConradFrix or OP is using a user instance. The problem is --- we just don't know.

Comment: Yes, please stop using the `user instances` feature. Aside from the fact that the feature is deprecated, it's just not meant for your application to actually use in a production environment - the feature is meant for local development.

Comment: The connection string stored in my website's web.config is: <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlinePhotoGalleryDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />. I did not need to attach to an instance in order for my website to use the database, and I'm quite sure it is not a file based database

Comment: You need to attach your database to your local instance, then change your connection string to get rid of all the AttachDbFileName/User Instance garbage. SQL Server is never a file-based database but you're trying to treat it like one.

Comment: @Aperture For future reference, extra information like this is best placed as an edit to the original question. (I've suggested an edit to your post including that last comment, and flagged the comment as obsolete).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Can you point me to some online sources that teach how to write a connection string?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382877/61305) from @marc_s - he explains how to create your database properly and how to connect to it. You can get all kinds of connection strings from http://connectionstrings.com/ and other resources you can search for just as well as I can, but your primary concern should be knocking off this `user instance` stuff.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Brilliant! Solved a fundamentally confusing problem. Thanks alot!