# Insert Into Statement doesn't throw an error but Data isn't inserted into table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

I can't find the answer to this problem anywhere. I'm trying to insert data into a SQL Server table. Everything seems to be OK with the statement, no errors throw when the command executes, but data isn't updated into the table...

Here is my code:

```
    public Boolean InsertRecordsToDB(string sColumns, String sParameters, string sValues, string sTable)
    {
        /// Split the parameter holding the values for the sql command parameters by the tab character and fill the appropriate arra\
        String[] sMyCols;
        sMyCols = sColumns.Split('\t');
        List<String> lstCols = new List<String>();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < sMyCols.Length; ii++)
        {
            lstCols.Add(sMyCols[ii]);
        }

        String[] sMyParams;
        sMyParams = sParameters.Split('\t');
        List<String> lstParams = new List<String>();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < sMyParams.Length; ii++)
        {
            lstParams.Add(sMyParams[ii]);
        }

        /// Split the values param and fill the array.  Using the parameter methodology as opposed to concatenating SQL strings prevents
        /// SQL injection
        string[] sMyValues;
        sMyValues = sValues.Split('\t');
        List<String> lstValues = new List<String>();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < sMyValues.Length; ii++)
        {
            lstValues.Add(sMyValues[ii]);
        }

        ///  Default connection string for the library project to be opened by the connection object
        String sConnString = LibraryProject.Properties.Settings.Default.db_ConnectionString;

        ///First build the Sql string based on the criteria passed in
        String sSql = "";
        sSql = "Insert Into [" + sTable + "] (";
        for (int j = 0; j < sMyCols.Length; j++)
        {
            int iParamLen = sMyCols.Length;
            int iParamMinusOne = iParamLen - 1;

            if (j.Equals(iParamMinusOne))
            {
                sSql += sMyCols[j] + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                sSql += sMyCols[j] + ",";
            }

            if (sSql.Substring(sSql.Length - 1).Equals(")"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        sSql += " Values(";
        for (int ii = 0; ii < sMyParams.Length; ii++)
        {
            int iParamLen = sMyParams.Length;
            int iParamLenMinusOne = iParamLen - 1;
            if (ii.Equals(iParamLenMinusOne))
            {
                sSql += sMyParams[ii].Substring(2) + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                sSql += sMyParams[ii].Substring(2) + ",";
            }

            if (sSql.Substring(sSql.Length - 1).Equals(")"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        ///  Create the connection object
        using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(sConnString))
        {
            oConn.Open();
            {


                try
                {
                    /// With the connection open instantiate an Sql command object
                    SqlCommand oMyCmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, oConn);
                    oMyCmd.Connection = oConn;
                    oMyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oMyCmd.CommandText = sSql;
                    int i = 0;

                    /// Assign the correct SQLDbType based on the preceding character of the parameter passed in (e.g. s_ = String/Text:  b_ = Boolean: d_ = Date)
                    foreach (String sParam in sMyParams)
                    {
                        switch (sParam.Substring(0, 2))
                        {
                            case "s_":
                                oMyCmd.Parameters.Add(sParam.Substring(2), SqlDbType.Text);

                                break;

                            case "b_":
                                oMyCmd.Parameters.Add(sParam.Substring(2), SqlDbType.Bit);
                                break;

                            case "d_":
                                oMyCmd.Parameters.Add(sParam.Substring(2), SqlDbType.Date);
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        oMyCmd.Parameters[sParam.Substring(2)].Value = lstValues[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    oMyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.ToString();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }

    }
```

Somebody please help me, I'm banging my head off of the wall here.

Here is the actual SQL statement after it's built:

```
Insert Into [tblBook] (ISBN, SERIAL_NUM, SUBJECT, TITLE, AUTHOR, PUBLISHER, GENRE)
Values(@ISBN, @SERIAL_NUM, @SUBJECT, @TITLE, @AUTHOR, @PUBLISHER, @GENRE)
```

The statement value was copied from the immediate window. I stopped execution at the `oMyCmd.ExecuteNotQuery();` line.

Comment: What numeric value is returned from oMyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery?   It should return number of rows inserted...

Comment: Can you post an example of the strings in your MyParams object? I have a hunch they might be missing the `@` symbol.. meaning, is it "b_@param" or "b_param"? The latter will not work and could explain your problem (I'm not sure if it would fail silently, though). The actual code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Sparky:  I'm not sure how I see the returned numeric value... let me consult Google and I'll post the answer

Comment: @David:  Here is the actual SQL Statement after it's built 
"Insert Into [tblBook] (ISBN,SERIAL_NUM,SUBJECT,TITLE,AUTHOR,PUBLISHER,GENRE) Values(@ISBN,@SERIAL_NUM,@SUBJECT,@TITLE,@AUTHOR,@PUBLISHER,@GENRE)"

The statement value was copied from the immediate window.  I stopped execution at the oMyCmd.ExecuteNotQuery(); line

Comment: That is valid SQL. Are you 100% sure there is no exception? I tested your code and it works perfectly. Now your SQL is also perfect. Therefore the problem is NOT code and NOT input; the only other variable left is the database connection itself. Have you debugged the code and put a breakpoint inside the catch block?

Comment: @Sparky:  The numeric return is 1... That does reflect the number of rows that should have been inserted..

Comment: I did a properties on the connection string and compared it to the string being output by the Settings.Default line.  With the exception of some directory placeholders, everything is identical.  This is the first time I've used SQL Server.  The solution only has one DB, so I'm  not sure how it would get the connection strings confused.  Is there a default database other than the one I created that I could be populating?  Is it possible I'm not viewing the table correctly? (Server Explorer > Right click tblBook > Show Table Data).  To be honest, I don't know what I'd look for in the try...catch

Comment: I stopped the code in the try catch and did a print on the connection string of the oMyCmd object... it was the same as listed on the properties of the database in the server explorer

Comment: The connection string from the 'Database1.mdf' on the right click is 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\LibraryProject\LibraryProject\LibraryProject\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True'

The oMyCmd.connection = 'ConnectionString: "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"'

Comment: I just noticed a small red 'X' in the bottom right corner of the Database.mdf under 'Data Connections'... could this be my problem?  what does the icon mean?

Comment: Ok I think I know the problem. You are using an attached database file. Chances are you have a copy in your working folder and one in the bin folder. You are probably inserting into one, and then looking for the result in the other.

Comment: See this question for a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382756/data-is-not-inserting-into-table

Comment: I had run across that question earlier, and forgive me for being thick (I'm not smart and you can't make me) but I guess that means I have to install SQL Server from the VS disc.  I had run across that post before, but I couldn't make any sense of it.  I'll try installing and re-creating the database tonight and using a different connection string.  I'll post tomorrow with the results.  Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: Sorry it took so long to approve... Moving to SQL Server Management Studio was exactly what I needed to do.